# Plugins not showing in dashboard->plugins section

Tags: plugins

About 60% of plugins that I install don't show up in my plugins section.

When I install them it says they're installed, and when I click "activate plugin" it says theres no valid header for the plugin. Navigating to the main plugin section in the dashboard the plugin doesn't show up at all, so I can't activate it from the main plugin page either.

What's wrong here. I'm not using the multi-site wordpress, just a standard wordpress installation with buddypress on top.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the plugin as a zip, extract and manually upload the folder that immediately parents all the .php files (i.e not a folder that has another folder as its child) into you plugin folder.

Sometimes dev's can zip things within an extra folder, which confuses wordpress.

Comment: I have no idea why that worked. Thats what I thought, but all the files seemed to match up and stuff... but its worked! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Per the WordPress Codex on plugin development, on [File Headers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers):

> The top of your Plugin's main PHP file
>   must contain a standard Plugin
>   information header. This header lets
>   WordPress recognize that your Plugin
>   exists, add it to the Plugin
>   management screen so it can be
>   activated, load it, and run its
>   functions; without the header, your
>   Plugin will never be activated and
>   will never run. Here is the header
>   format:
>
> ```
> <?php
> /*
> Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
> Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
> Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
> Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
> Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
> Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
> License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
> */
> ?>
> ```
>
> The minimum information WordPress
>   needs to recognize your Plugin is the
>   Plugin Name line.

If I had to guess, I'd say the problem is that the `Plugin Name` header is missing from the top of the plugin's main file. Not knowing what plugins you're using, this is the most complete answer I can give right now.

### EDIT

I should add that in order for a file to be checked for headers, it must be a `.php` file either in the plugins directory or in a subdirectory of the plugins directory. So, for example, `wp-content/plugins/plugin.php` and `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/plugin.php` would be valid, but `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/lib/file.php` would not.

Comment: I think you meant `my-plugin.php` for the `my-plugin` folder?

Comment: my plugins have the header set but aren't recognized anyway... What could be the problem instead?

Answer (score 2):

On my Debian installation, the plugins are in /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins and I needed a symlink before the plugin could be found/activated:

```
/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/plugins$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/treepress
```